# How to extract param from url in javascript

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-chrome-extension, spotify

I have this url that is provided by the `chrome.identity.getRedirectURL()` function

```
https://jjjnkdmnhdhmfjdlmbljoiclmbojbiec.chromiumapp.org/#access_token=BQDhJnhA4NV2V-2Cn5xYwQyPz4QI5EdY3cu5nNqfgvVt4p4K8fKYtmlfp8ZQYS65ww2rUAZQ7chyZnPDZLlKJEyCfZBRxtr6Q1FpRe9UuiTJ2hT9SMNb-icodIc-I9ADauULDf4JVqvVXoHz1hWvpDWnqln8Yus&token_type=Bearer&expires_in=3600
```

I need to get the `access_token` param value to store the token and use it later with spotify api. What is the best method I can use in javascript?

Comment: "Best" depends on multiple factors so this question attracts opinionated answers. Simply use any method like string splitting or using URLSearchParams API.

Comment: ok thank you. I will opt for the `URLSearchParams` API

Comment: @wOxxOm wrong...... it is not a querysring

Comment: Yeah I guess it's not a query string

Comment: @epascarello, URLSearchParams can work with any string, including a substring extracted from a URL's hash.

Comment: `new URL(str).hash.match(/access_token=([^&]+)/)[1];` or `new URL(str.split("#").join("?")).searchParams.get('access_token')`

Comment: @wOxxOm to extract from the hash the api will work using the `.get()` method?

Comment: `var url = 'completeURL'.split('#')` 
`var access_token = url[1].slice(12,172) `
use this code

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you have a url like `https://some-url?access_token=1234` you can use `URLSearchParams`.

```
// window location search returns '?access_token=1234' if the url is 'https://some-url?access_token=1234'
const params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
const token = params.get('access_token');
```

Update Regex

```
const x = new RegExp(/(#access_token=).*?(&)+/);

const str = 'https://jjjnkdmnhdhmfjdlmbljoiclmbojbiec.chromiumapp.org/#access_token=BQDhJnhA4NV2V-2Cn5xYwQyPz4QI5EdY3cu5nNqfgvVt4p4K8fKYtmlfp8ZQYS65ww2rUAZQ7chyZnPDZLlKJEyCfZBRxtr6Q1FpRe9UuiTJ2hT9SMNb-icodIc-I9ADauULDf4JVqvVXoHz1hWvpDWnqln8Yus&token_type=Bearer&expires_in=3600';

// Use String.prototype.match and pass the Regex 
const result = String(str).match(x);
console.log(result);

// returns
[
  "#access_token=BQDhJnhA4NV2V-2Cn5xYwQyPz4QI5EdY3cu5…9SMNb-icodIc-I9ADauULDf4JVqvVXoHz1hWvpDWnqln8Yus&", 
  "#access_token=", "&", 
  index: 57, 
  input: "https://jjjnkdmnhdhmfjdlmbljoiclmbojbiec.chromiuma…1hWvpDWnqln8Yus&token_type=Bearer&expires_in=3600", 
  groups: undefined
]

// Access the matching substring if there is one using
result[0];
// "#access_token=BQDhJnhA4NV2V-2Cn5xYwQyPz4QI5EdY3cu5nNqfgvVt4p4K8fKYtmlfp8ZQYS65ww2rUAZQ7chyZnPDZLlKJEyCfZBRxtr6Q1FpRe9UuiTJ2hT9SMNb-icodIc-I9ADauULDf4JVqvVXoHz1hWvpDWnqln8Yus&"
```

PLEASE NOTE THAT THE BEGINNING `#` AND ENDING `&` ARE INCLUDING WITH THIS REGULAR EXPRESSION.

Comment: If the token is not a query param but is instead a `path` param then you would use a `regular expression`.

Comment: ok thank you. I think that the URLSearchParams API will be ok. If you can show an example with a regex it will be appreciated. :)

Comment: Unsure how it is marked as an answer. Hash is not going to be parsed as.a Search Param.

Comment: var url = 'completeURL'.split('#')
var access_token = url[1].slice(12,172)
user this code to get access_token only

Comment: Answer updated :)